# MUI Grid xs item doesn't shrink

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, css-grid

I've created a small Dashboard in order to view achievements of some sort (won't get into details). The page consists in small boxes with certain information and to make them responsive I've used MUI Grid.

```
<Box>
  <Grid container spacing={3}>
    <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={6}>
      <SelfNumberOfQuizzes />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={6}>
      <SelfPointsInPeriod period={period} />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
  <Grid container spacing={3} mt={1.5}>
    <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={6}>
      <SelfNumberOfQuizzesByDifficulty />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={6}>
      <SelfPointsByDifficultyInPeriod period={period} />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
  <Grid container spacing={3} mt={1.5}>
    <Grid item xs={12} md={12} lg={12}>
      <SelfAnswersByDifficulty />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Box>
```

The page looks good and it works just fine when trying to shrink when lg or md (the inside items shrinks as well to be fully visible). However, once the page is small enough to use xs prop, the items don't shrink anymore, the width looks fixed.

[image: MD VIEW]

[image: XS VIEW]

First picture -> MD
Second picture -> XS

You can see the horizontal scroll bar when it starts to be XS. The components within each grid item don't have width specified.

Comment: Without the `Grid` containers, I mean if you have only the top `Box` component, then is it responsive?